# Progress dialog never shows up

Tags: android, fragment, progressdialog

I am trying to show a progress dialog on click of a list item, but the progress dialog never shows up.

Surprisingly, mProgressdialog.isShowing() is true. Please provide some insight into the problem if any one has faced similar issues.

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new Adapter.ListClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {



                                    //Some computations done.

                                    if (ProjectsFragment.this.getActivity() != null) {

                                        UniversalProgressDialog.showSimpleProgressDialog(getActivity(),"Loading","Loading...",false);

          android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = ProjectsFragment.this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, new AgendaFragment(), "AGENDA");
                    ft.commit();



                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        });
```

Source code for UniversalProgressDialog :-

```
    public class UniversalProgressDialog {

        private static ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


        public static void showSimpleProgressDialog(Context context, String title,
                                                    String msg, boolean isCancelable) {
            try {
                if (mProgressDialog == null) {
                    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, msg);
                    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                    mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                }

                if(mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                if (!mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mProgressDialog.show();
                }

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                re.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void removeSimpleProgressDialog() {
            try {
                if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                    if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        mProgressDialog = null;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();

            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                re.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
```

What have I tried?

Tried moving the progress dialog showing code to

Tried moving fragment transition code to another thread like below:-

```
 private class PerformFragmentTransition extends Thread {


        public PerformFragmentTransition() {
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = ProjectsFragment.this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, new AgendaFragment(), "AGENDA");
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

Also tried :-

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                public void run() {
                                    UniversalProgressDialog.showSimpleProgressDialog(getActivity(),"Loading","Loading...",false);

                                }
                            });
```

Also tried :-

As per one of the commments, I commented out the fragment transition code and the progress dialog showed up.

If at all this gives some clue on how to fix the problem,
 and more information :-
 I will dismiss the progress dialog in the next fragment after it has been loaded.

Comment: I think your fragment is popping up above your progress dialog.

Comment: I think dialog shows but it quickly opens the screens. So Add some delay in Thread. May be it works.

Comment: try by `UniversalProgressDialog.showSimpleProgressDialog(ProjectsFragment.this.getActivity(),"Loading","Loading...",false);`

Comment: Just to comment the fragment transaction code and try.

Comment: @ShaluTD How is ProjectsFragment.this.getActivity() and getActivity() different?

Comment: `ProgressDialog.show(context, title, msg);` created and shows dialog immediately . Use `new ProgressDialog()` . Apart from that  `ProgressDialog` is depricated in API26. And for your answer try the put a `Handler` with `postDelay()` to check .

Comment: @ShaluTD When I commented fragment transaciont code it showed up. But I want to do the fragment transaction as well, so please help.

And further information, I am dismissing the dialog in the next fragment.

Comment: @AIK If that is the case how can I get it fixed?

Comment: Just use ProgressBar instead of progressDialog

Comment: @Google how are they different wrt the context of the problem that I am facing?

Comment: Is it necessary to use progressDialog? because i don't see any code that takes a lot of time to retrieve data.

Comment: @AIK That code is in the next fragment.

Comment: So what you need to do is open the fragment first and then in its onCreateView() show your progress dialog and when the data is retrieved dismiss your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, msg);
```

replace the code above code with below code :

```
 mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(title);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(msg);
```

the problem is you are showing dialog while it is creating in your code 
before setting required property to it. and please remove try catch block so you will get the error what actually error is occur. and can see in console